# Gui for Xamarin SQLite Database

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin, netbeans

I am new to app development and have followed this Tutorial in order to creat an SQlite database for my xamarin application. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736454.aspx

Everythings worked fine I am only wondering if there's some kind of gui in order to manipulate database entries without using code?
Maybe something similar to netbeans?

Thank you.

Comment: DB Browser for SQLite : https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: @SushiHangover ah. I came across this already when I was researching. I wasn't sure if I can use this for a xamarin application. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to create a GUI for viewing the database tables, you will have to pull the db file from the device and view it using a SQLite database viewer/editor. There are many open source and free database browsers available. I have written a detailed [blog](https://libinjoseph.com/2019/access-your-sqlite/)
. Please check it

Comment: Hi Joseph, does this also work when using an android emulator?

Comment: @TobiasGerling: As long as the emulator is running it should work. Do u have any issues?

Comment: Now it works. I somehome ejected the virtual sd card. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TobiasGerling: Glad it helped. If it answers your question. Please mark it as answer